# Getting Type Error Result expression while running Phonegap android app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have created and app and loaded js files

its giving following Error:

`06-07 16:15:36.691: D/CordovaLog(1465): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.call' [undefined] is not a function.
06-07 16:15:36.691: E/Web Console(1465): TypeError: Result of expression 'this.call' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.3.2.js:3032
06-07 16:15:36.757: D/Cordova(1465): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to use lastest stable jQuery-mobile version([1.3.1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/04/10/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-1/)) and the suggested jQuery version ([1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js)), (just `jQuery` if ur not using jqmobile ofc)

It might be some version issue